# How Do I Stop App Store Notifications about Xcode Version Updates?

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store

I've already downloaded the latest version (8.1 at this time) from [Apple's direct download page](https://developer.apple.com/download/).

Answer (score 0):

While attempting to solve a similar issue on my own Macbook, I had found that the App Store will try to discover updates for apps it has indexed in Spotlight.  This apparently includes the backup copy of xcode 7 it found on my Time Machine disk.

The asking of a second xcode download only occurred when my Time Machine disk was mounted (and when I did attempt to update it, it would always fail with permission errors).  The fix for me was to tell Spotlight not to index my backup disk.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that will help because I have Xcode in a folder that's pretty important for Spotlight indexing (`/Applications').